# Prove that $\int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{(1-k)(\ln x)^{k}}$ $k \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration

For fun I studied the following integral

$$
 \int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}} 
$$
and of course I wanted to solve it. I started with $k=1$, which gives us the following
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^2} = -\frac{1}{\ln x}.
$$
Then for $k=2$, we get the following
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^3} = -\frac{1}{2(\ln x)^2}.
$$
From the above, I drew the conclusion that it might be true that

$$
\int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^a} = \frac{1}{(1-a)(\ln x)^{a-1}}.
$$

By assuming it is true for $a=k$, then  for  $a=k+1$ we get that

$$
\int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}} = \int \frac{1}{x (\ln x)^{k}} \frac{1}{\ln x}dx = \frac{1}{(1-k)(\ln x)^{k-1}}\frac{1}{\ln x} + \int \frac{dx}{(1-k)(\ln x)^{k-1}} \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\\ \Leftrightarrow 
$$
$$
\int \left(1 - \frac{1}{1-k} \right) \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}}= \int \left( \frac{k}{k-1} \right) \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{(1-k)(\ln x)^{k}} \Leftrightarrow \\
$$
$$
 \int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}} =\frac{1}{-k(\ln x)^{k}} =\frac{1}{(1-(k+1))(\ln x)^{k}}. 
$$

Now, I wonder what happends if $k \in \mathbb{R}$? Could I use the **abowe** result to draw any conclusions for $k \in \mathbb{R}?$

Yes, I know I can verify $\int \frac{dx}{x (\ln x)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{(1-k)(\ln x)^{k-1}}$ by taking the derivative with $k \in \mathbb{R}$. I also know that you can do a substitution to find it. But I would like to find a solution without this.

Comment: Substitute $u = \log(x)$ to get a simple integral that you can evaluate directly to the result. This derivation is valid for all real $k\not= 1$.

Comment: Why not use substitution $y=\ln x$?

Comment: @Winther yes I get that, and I know that all I have done is unnecessary work. But I would want to do it without substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\ln x$ and $du=\frac{dx}{x}$. This yields

$$\int \frac{du}{u^{k+1}}=\int u^{-k-1}du=\frac{u^{-k}}{-k}+C=\frac{\ln^{-k}|x|}{-k}+C$$

Comment: Well ofc, but that is not what I am looking for. I guess this is one offf those integrals where you pretty much have to do a substitution

Comment: I am just doing this fot fun, and I know there is simpler ways. I want to find out if there is a way without substitution

Comment: Substitution is the best way to proceed here. I believe that you are trying to use induction. Thus, you have only proved the statement for positive integer values of $k$, where I have proved it for all real $k \neq 1$.

Comment: What do you mean by trying? Why have I not succed? Yes, I understand your sol. but I wanted to do it without substitution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts we have $$\int\frac{1}{x\log^{k+1}\left(x\right)}dx=\frac{1}{\log^{k}\left(x\right)}+\left(k+1\right)\int\frac{1}{x\log^{k+1}\left(x\right)}dx
 $$ then $$-k\int\frac{1}{x\log^{k+1}\left(x\right)}dx=\frac{1}{\log^{k}\left(x\right)}
 $$ and so $$\int\frac{1}{x\log^{k+1}\left(x\right)}dx=-\frac{1}{k\log^{k}\left(x\right)}+C.$$